# How to setting layout for grouped bars?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm beginner in D3.js and I need to create a Pivot Chart that shows the sales results of two salespeople.

When I select seller A or B the chart automatically renders with my jsonFile data.

I simulated the graphics in excel to show how I'm trying to get it to look:

[image]

**Chart as it is now:**

[image]

Currently, in my code, it is rendering only sales from the last year.

**My Code:**

```js
//set up data
var sales = [
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
        "Vendas_Ano": 21611.950000000004,
        "Vendas_Ant": 16033.31
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
        "Vendas_Ano": 48108.08,
        "Vendas_Ant": 51142.299999999996
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
        "Vendas_Ano": 13427.280000000004,
        "Vendas_Ant": 21274.129999999997
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
        "Vendas_Ano": 28553.83,
        "Vendas_Ant": 15228.569999999998
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
        "Vendas_Ano": 19639.59,
        "Vendas_Ant": 10291.359999999999
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22530.840000000007,
        "Vendas_Ant": 21905.29
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
        "Vendas_Ano": 20216.759999999995,
        "Vendas_Ant": 8276
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
        "Vendas_Ano": 39832.04,
        "Vendas_Ant": 49810.810000000005
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Set",
        "Vendas_Ano": 12861.52,
        "Vendas_Ant": 24425.32
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Out",
        "Vendas_Ano": 9227.34,
        "Vendas_Ant": 17804.65
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 9993.34
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "CHARNECA",
        "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 36568.7
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jan",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22681.14,
        "Vendas_Ant": 28587.71
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Fev",
        "Vendas_Ano": 31382.11,
        "Vendas_Ant": 37637.420000000006
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mar",
        "Vendas_Ano": 32453.779999999995,
        "Vendas_Ant": 32993.12
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Apr",
        "Vendas_Ano": 23445.4,
        "Vendas_Ant": 30835.75
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Mai",
        "Vendas_Ano": 16471.71,
        "Vendas_Ant": 18028.07
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jun",
        "Vendas_Ano": 11617.470000000001,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22651.53
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Jul",
        "Vendas_Ano": 24699.44,
        "Vendas_Ant": 34152.28999999999
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Ago",
        "Vendas_Ano": 35476.94000000001,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22069.699999999997
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Set",
        "Vendas_Ano": 37462.92,
        "Vendas_Ant": 23120.08
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Out",
        "Vendas_Ano": 22042.140000000003,
        "Vendas_Ant": 28449.95
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Nov",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 30755.050000000003
    },
    {
        "vendnm": "JOÃO LUIS",
        "MonthAbrev": "Dez",
        "Vendas_Ano": 0,
        "Vendas_Ant": 22838.64
    }
]

var charnecaData = [];
var joaoData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
    if (sales[i]["vendnm"] === "CHARNECA") {
        charnecaData.push(sales[i]);
    } else {
        joaoData.push(sales[i]);
    }
}

//functions for toggling between data
function change(value) {
    if (value === 'lastYear') {
        update(charnecaData);
    } else if (value === 'currentYear') {
        update(joaoData);
    }
}

function update(data) {

    xChart.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.MonthAbrev; }));

    yChart.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.Vendas_Ant > d.Vendas_Ano ? d.Vendas_Ant : d.Vendas_Ano; })]);

    var barWidth = xChart.bandwidth() / 2;

    var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .remove()
        .exit()
        .data(data)

    bars.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return xChart(d.MonthAbrev) + barWidth * ((d.vendnm == 'CHARNECA') ? 0.2 : 1) })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return yChart(d.Vendas_Ant); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - yChart(d.Vendas_Ant); })
        .attr("width", barWidth - 5)
        .attr("fill", function (d) {
            if (d.vendnm === 'CHARNECA') {
                return "rgb(251,180,174)";
            } else {
                return "rgb(179,205,227)";
            }
        })
        .on("mouseover", function (a) {
            chart.append("text")
                .attr("class", "title-text")
                .style("fill", "rgb(44, 160, 44)")
                .text(
                    a.vendnm + ' - ' +
                    a.MonthAbrev + ' - ' +
                    Number(Math.round(a.Vendas_Ant * 100) / 100).toLocaleString("es-ES", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }) + '€'
                )
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("x", 400)
                .attr("y", 50);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (a) {
            chart.select(".title-text").remove();
        })

    //left axis
    chart.select('.y')
        .call(yAxis)
    //bottom axis
    chart.select('.xAxis')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate(-65)";
        });

}//end update

var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
var width = 600;
var height = 300;

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var xChart = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width]);

var yChart = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xChart);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yChart);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-65)";
    });

update(sales);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Index 6</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<style>
    .radio {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .row {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='radio'>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="lastYear" onclick='change(this.value)'> Charneca
                </label>
                <label class='radio-inline'>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="currentYear" onclick='change(this.value)'> João Luis
                </label>
            </div>
            <svg class='chart'>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This test I'm doing is based on the code in this link: https://bl.ocks.org/syncopika/f1c9036b0deb058454f825238a95b6be

I know I'm close to achieving the result, as I said I'm still a beginner and sometimes D3.js is so verbose and it confuses me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi there! Is there a reason you're not using the `i` variable when placing the x axis? Also, there's no set value with your radio buttons when the page renders. I did notice that the code snippet runs with two bars until you click on a radio button.

Comment: Hii Ryan, First of all, thanks for you help. I apologize, but I did not quite understand what I meant by the x axis. You refer to `return xChart (d.MonthAbrev) + barWidth * ((d.vendnm == 'CHARNECA')? 0.2: 1)` ?. This function I did to coordinate each data point. I don't know how to use `i` with her to achieve my goal. Also, I don't know how to set the button value to when the page is rendered.